# Javascript Initializing Geofire gives error that it is not a constructor

Tags: firebase, geofire

I am new to geofire and wanted to use the geoquery function to get the nearest people in my database who are within 5 km radius from the center coordinates that I specify. However, I am having problem in calling geofire to point to my database. I am attaching the code here:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var GeoFire = require('geofire');
var geoFire = new GeoFire(firebase.database().ref());
var geoQuery = geoFire.query({
  center: [10.38, 2.41],
  radius: 10.5
});
```

But it is giving the following error:
TypeError: GeoFire is not a constructor

Please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: You're not requiring `geofire` anywhere. Since it's not part of the Firebase SDK, you'll need to import it separately

Comment: shoudn't it be like this: var geoFireInstance = new geofire.GeoFire(firebaseRef);